# How to get the path to current theme, but from a JS file?

Tags: jquery, json

I made a child theme from the default twentyseventeen theme. I'm loading a javascript file on functions.php using:

```
wp_enqueue_script('testpage', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/testscript.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
```

Then on that javascript file I'm trying to use load a .json using `jQuery.getJSON`. The .json file is in the same directory as the .js file. Since I enqueued the script using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`, I assumed the current path from that .js would be the path it's located inside the theme? But apparently that's not the case. If I try to to load the .json using a relative path to the same directory, then I get a 404.

`jQuery.getJSON("mydata.json")` will 404 because it's actually looking at `www.mysite.com/js/mydata.json` and not at `www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/js/mydata.json`

So I fixed it by just using `jQuery.getJSON("/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/js/mydata.json")` This works fine, currently.

But I'm afraid that doing so isn't good practice? Hard coding the whole theme path like that in the JS file is bad, because that directory can change depending on installation, right? So is there some way to get the current theme path? Similar to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` in PHP? Or maybe there's some other way entirely of doing this that would avoid this problem? Or is this no problem at all and I can just keep it like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`wp_localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) to pass an object with the url to load before the file. and then in the file you can use it like `testpage_obj.json_data`

```
wp_register_script('testpage', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/testscript.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
wp_localize_script( 'testpage', 'testpage_obj', array(
    'json_data' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/mydata.json'
) );
wp_enqueue_script('testpage');
```

In the JS file

```
jQuery.getJSON(testpage_obj.json_data)
```